# Python ModuleNotFoundError snowflake-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Python script having:

```
import os
import time
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import cloudinary as cd
import sqlalchemy
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.connector.errors import ProgrammingError
import json
...
```

However when I am trying to run it I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.sqlalchemy'; 'snowflake' is not a package
```

snowflake-sqlalchemy is installed so this is something else I can't find.

EDIT as per request:

Following have been installed as required:

```
pandas
snowflake
snowflake-sqlalchemy
snowflake-connector-python
sqlalchemy
requests
cloudinary
```

```
root@3e2a17b9a15c:/# pip show snowflake
Name: snowflake
Version: 0.0.3
Summary: Simple persistent unique IDs.
Home-page: https://github.com/shaddi/snowflake
Author: Shaddi Hasan
Author-email: shaddih@gmail.com
License: bsd
Location: /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Comment: It's installed, but is it installed to the same environment you're running scripts in?

Comment: @snakecharmerb no, I don't.

Comment: @RandomDavis it should be as there is no virtual env.

Comment: @snakecharmerb so there is snowflake.py in `<module 'snowflake' from '/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake.py'>` what does it mean and how to fix this? (I am not Python dev)

Comment: It means that somehow, someone has installed a package (?) that has created a file named snowflake.py in your system, and this is preventing snowflake.sqlalchemy being imported.  If you run `pip show snowflake` in the terminal, what do you get (please [edit] this info into the question).

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes it was installed as per requirements (snowflake, snowflake-sqlalchemy, snowflake-connector-python) does this mean they all shoudln't be installed?

Comment: To me, `snowflake` looks unrelated to snowflake the database, so I would uninstall it (`pip uninstall snowflake`).  But you might want to consult with whoever gave you the requirements.

Comment: removing `snowflake` package solved the issue. thanks @snakecharmerb